# Merge multiple rows with same value into a single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm doing some exercise with northwind database and I have written the following query :

```
select 
    Employees.EmployeeID, year(Orders.OrderDate) as Year, 
    count(Employees.EmployeeID) as 'Total Orders'
from  
    Orders 
join 
    Employees on Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
where 
    year(Orders.OrderDate) = '1996'
group by 
    Employees.EmployeeID, Orders.OrderDate
order by 
    Employees.EmployeeID asc
```

I get the following output:

```
EmployeeID | Year | Total Orders
-----------+------+--------------
1          |1996  | 1
1          |1996  | 1
1          |1996  | 2
1          |1996  | 1
1          |1996  | 1
....
```

I think the problem is `year(Orders.OrderDate)` part because original date have month, day,...

Any help with be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`group by Employees.EmployeeID, year(Orders.OrderDate)`

As far as I know, you can group by a function.

Edit: Also, you generally can't group by an alias representing a function unless it's evaluated first in a sub query.

Comment: now that's truly embarrassing, I totally didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

whenever using group by clause, We should use the all the fields without alias name from select clause as it is except aggregate operations.

In your case, your group by clause should be

group by Employees.EmployeeID, year(Orders.OrderDate)